# Is it possible/advisable to reuse StaticQuery objects in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I intended to define my Slick queries a single time and reuse them whenever I needed them, but I ran into a NullPointerException that I traced down to the same StaticQuery0 object being used twice in the same session.  Are Query and StaticQuery objects meant to be reused this way?  Is there a better way to approach this (such as creating a new query object each time?)  Or am I triggering the exception through some other mistake?

Here are the details of the error.  name.query is a StaticQuery0 created via StaticQuery.queryNA.  Reusing it in different sessions works:

```
import Database.threadLocalSession
val points = db withSession {
  name.query.to[Vector]
}
val points2 = db withSession {
  name.query.to[Vector] // No problem!
}
```

Using it a second time in the same session throws a NullPointerException:

```
import Database.threadLocalSession
val points = db withSession {
  name.query.to[Vector]
  name.query.to[Vector] // Kablam!
}
```

Here's the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializeResultsMetadataFromCache(ConnectionImpl.java:5552)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1368)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:34)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.elementsTo(StatementInvoker.scala:17)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.foreach(Invoker.scala:90)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.foreach(StatementInvoker.scala:10)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.build(Invoker.scala:66)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.build(StatementInvoker.scala:10)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.to(Invoker.scala:74)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.to(StatementInvoker.scala:10)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.UnitInvoker$class.to(Invoker.scala:152)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery0.to(StaticQuery.scala:        
    at (the second call to name.query.to[Vector])
```